# Encrypting mails with special characters in attachment names

Tags: smime, mimekit

I'm using MimeKit for creating s/mime encrypted mails with attachments.
As soon as an attachment name has special chars, e.g. äüö, the attachemnt name gets lost and is displayed like "unnamend attachment 123.dat" in Outlook.
Unencrypted mails do fine, so the only difference is just msg.Encrypt(context).

Are there some constraints in MimeKit regarding this use case or do I have to do more to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the `ContentType` and `ContentDisposition` parameters of the attachment (before encrypting) and set the `EncodingMethod` of each parameter to `ParameterEncodingMethod.Rfc2047`.

The problem is probably that Outlook can't handle rfc2231-style encoding of parameter values.

example:

```
foreach (var param in attachment.ContentType.Parameters)
    param.EncodingMethod = ParameterEncodingMethod.Rfc2047;
foreach (var param in attachment.ContentDisposition.Parameters)
    param.EncodingMethod = ParameterEncodingMethod.Rfc2047;
```